# PHP monitor for end of file from PDO query

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using PHP with PDO to access a MySql database table.  Is there a MySQL SQLCODE I can monitor for when my PDO query reaches end of file?

Comment: Did you mean end of result *set* perhaps? If you utilize the [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/PDOStatement) iterator, your `foreach` will cease with the last row anyway.

Comment: I've never heard the concept of EOF applied to relational databases. If you want to learn how to use the PDO libraries, you should find plenty of code samples in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/pdo). Please edit the question and clarify what you want to know exactly.

Comment: I came here looking around for a way to wrap PDO as ADO (to migrate old applications using it) - found this as a way to get the EOF: http://imrannazar.com/Interfacing-ADODB-to-PDO

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `VB` terminology where  `ADO` recordsets used 
the end of file to allow you to determine if you were at the end of the recordset or not.

Such notion is different in this context

You can get the last row  by fetching the following way:

```
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
```

or Perhaps you want to fetch the whole recordset, and get the last value.

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
$eof = array_pop($data);
```

Comment: please justify the the -1